# Angular 4 Get Position of a HTML Element

Tags: angular

I am working on a custom UI element where users will move a circle on a square as an input. 
For that i need the circle to follow the mouse when the mouse enters the square.
In javascript that is quite easy as shown here:
https://www.kirupa.com/canvas/follow_mouse_cursor.htm

When i try to do it now in angular, i am not sure what the correct way to do it is. 
I need the offset from the square. For that i need to access the square element.
All the solutions i found used ElementRef and it's easy to make it work that way and seems to be the common way. 
[angular 2 / typescript : get hold of an element in the template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32693061/angular-2-typescript-get-hold-of-an-element-in-the-template)

But on angular.io  it's said to not use it.
It's even listed as a rookie mistake http://angularjs.blogspot.de/2016/04/5-rookie-mistakes-to-avoid-with-angular.html.
It says to use invokeElment and viewChild.
But the offcial solution doesn't work anymore because invokeElement does not exist in Renderer2.

So what is the right way to do it?
Can i use ElementRef an be good normally? Am i understanding something fundamentally wrong?

Comment: I mostly use ElementRef and did not tried anything else. i think officially in there site they are using it. not sure about other blogs

Comment: Why don't you use viewchild